# How do you draw complex shapes with multiple points and elevations using cesiumjs.(ex. radar search fence)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cesiumjs

I am trying to draw something similar to a radar search fence. I am finding this difficult and have tried many different types of entities to draw them. The blue fence in this picture is an example of something I am trying to draw. Here is some code that got me the furthest along but still is not correct

```
 var orangePolygon = viewer.entities.add({
        name: 'Orange polygon with per-position heights and outline',
        polygon: {
            hierarchy: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights(
                [155.5, 54.37139, 50000,
                    154.5, 54.37139, 50000,
                    135.87694, 72.37139, 500000,
                    175.87694, 72.37139, 500000
                ]),
            extrudedHeight: 600000,
            perPositionHeight: true,
            material: Cesium.Color.ORANGE.withAlpha(0.5),
            outline: true,
            outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK
        }
    });
```

What I'm trying to replicate or at least something similar

[search fence picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qgb0.jpg)